# Which is the preferred solution for Kotlin koan "Partition" and why?

Tags: kotlin, partition

I worked through the Kotlin koan Partition and came wound up with this, which passes the unit test:

```
    fun Shop.getCustomersWithMoreUndeliveredOrdersThanDelivered(): Set<Customer> = 
        customers.filter{it.orders.partition{it.isDelivered}
             .let{(delivered, undelivered) -> delivered.size < undelivered.size}}.toSet()
```

This is a variation on the solution:

```
    fun Shop.getCustomersWithMoreUndeliveredOrdersThanDelivered(): Set<Customer> = 
        customers.filter {
            val (delivered, undelivered) = it.orders.partition { it.isDelivered }
            undelivered.size > delivered.size
        }.toSet()
```

Are there any reasons to prefer one of these solutions over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin Koans were written for Kotlin 1.0 which didn't support destructuring in lambda parameters.

Otherwise, if you're targeting Kotlin 1.1, these two solutions are equivalent.